# AWS loadbalancer per packet - only iptables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Need a design advice. Need to run in AWS loadbalancer per packet (not per flow).
It's for unidirectional UDP based streaming.
That means that each packet received by the loadbalancer should be send to another target - so that all targets receive the same amount of packets.

I do not see any ready solution and considering using EC2 with iptables and "-m statistic --mode random" PREROUTING chain. Any comments on the performance of that module at 1 up to 10Gbit/s scale ? (how strong EC2 instance would i need?)

Any other advices / hints how to achieve it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Network Loadbalancer can be configured to send to "random" Targets in the TargetGroup, but this behaviour is not documented and just stated (to be exact, it's not defined how this distribution is done). It's the general ELB behaviour that targets are chosen by some hidden algorithm. Maybe it's worth an experiment? Make sure that Stickiness is turned off, as this is enabled the exact opposite of your use case.

I couldn't find a hard definition of how many GBit/s a NLB will support. But there is the concept of LCU (Load Balancer Capacity Units) that determines also billing and needs to be taken into account. LCUs are exposed in [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html)

Custom EC2 Instances will work and also cost a lot as CPU scales (roughly) with network. [Here](https://instances.vantage.sh) is a general list of EC2 Instances that you can filter for your network requirements and also see the pricing for it.

Maybe you should generally go for Devices with Enhanced Networking and Nitro, as later have special hardware for fast networking.

Comment: thanks for the comments @Augunrik, for now i use EC2 with iptables and it works fine.